# PHP mail headers "base64 encoded unnecessarily"

Tags: php, email, base64, spam

## What I have:

I'm using the PHP mail function to send an email. My headers are as follows:

```
    <?php
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
               ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"
               ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
               ."From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode($from_name) 
               ."?= <$from_address>\r\n"
               ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f $from_address");
    ?>
```

This code is sourced from an accepted stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801159/835950

## My problem:

Spam Assassin is applying a 0.1 penalty for the following reason:

> 0.1 FROM_EXCESS_BASE64     From: base64 encoded unnecessarily

## My question:

How should I modify my headers to avoid this penalty. Do I simply remove the base64_encode function?

Answer (score 3):

You need to detect if base64-encoding UTF-8 is truly needed, or if all characters are within ASCII range. This is a bit ugly but works:

```
<?php
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
           ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"
           ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
           ."From: ".(preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', $from_name)?
            "=?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode($from_name) ."?=" : $from_name )
           ." <$from_address>\r\n"
           ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f $from_address");
?>
```

Alternatively you could detect the character set using [mb_check_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php), but this regular expression keeps it short.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with $from_names that were stored as UTF-8 in a MySQL database. I could avoid the 0.01 penalty when base64 encoding was not necessary with a solution like this:

```
<?php
function encode_from($s) {
    if (mb_check_encoding($s, 'ASCII'))
        return mb_convert_encoding($s, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8');
    else
        return "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($s)."?=";
}
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
           ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"
           ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
           ."From: " . encode_from($from_name)
           ." <$from_address>\r\n"
           ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f $from_address");
?>
```

Spam Assassin is still applying a penalty when UTF-8 encoding is really necessary, but that was a bug in Spam Assassin, which has been fixed upstream:

https://bz.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=7730

Comment: Why returning mb_convert_encoding($s, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8') and not only $s ?

Answer (score -1):

I would remove the base64 encoding and try it.

Concerning [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

I wouldn't think that it's binary data coming in there as $from_name

Comment: When I remove the function, I get recieve a higher (worse) Spam Assassin score: `1.7 BAD_ENC_HEADER Message has bad MIME encoding in the header`. I'm defining $from_name myself. It's just a textual string.

Comment: i looked around a bit and seems most solutions use the base 64 encoder when generating the mail header, i don't know if there is another encoding which would fit better

Comment: Well, at least we know it's needed; I'm not sure why Spam Assassin deems it as "unnecessary".